# Getting Solana Metaplex Candy Machine Config Data

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, metaplex, candy-machine

I have been looking for the best way to find mainnet config data given a Candy Machine ID. This config data would consist of mint price, supply, items available, and go live date. I have seen some webapps display this kind of data to a front end but I can't remember which webapp it was.

After searching, it seems like I will need to do some sort of web3 RPC magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine` package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine

Here is the `CandyMachine` class for reference https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/candy-machine/js/src/generated/accounts/CandyMachine.ts#L34=

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is using [project-serum anchor](https://coral-xyz.github.io/anchor/ts/index.html) with the CandyMachineIDL (you can fetch it using [this](https://coral-xyz.github.io/anchor/ts/classes/Program.html#fetchIdl)). Then you just have to use the [fetch function](https://coral-xyz.github.io/anchor/ts/classes/StateClient.html#fetch) over the CandyMachine Account, in order to have an already decoded data of the [CandyMachine state](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/candy-machine/program/src/state.rs#L6) (check that the data that you wanna look is inside `candyMachine.data`).

[Here is a really good example!](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/blob/e526e9ad8b4bcf56e97d487f70eaf8539bb40eee/js/packages/candy-machine-ui/src/candy-machine.ts#L174-L181)